# How to pass a dictionary of Queues to multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am not sure if it is possible to pass an dictionary of Queues as argument to a Process. If it is only possible as kwargs, how can it be done?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class WordsManager:

    def __init__(self, my_dict):
        self.dict = my_dict

    def run(self):
        pass


def words_worker(my_dict):
    worker = WordsManager(my_dict)
    worker.run()


def start_job_manager():
    my_dict = {}
    for language in ('en', 'de', 'es'):
        my_dict[language] = Queue()

    words_manager = {'process': None, 'my_dict': my_dict}
    words_manager["process"] = Process(target=words_worker, args=(words_manager['my_dict']))
    words_manager["process"].daemon = True
    words_manager["process"].start()

    return words_manager


start_job_manager()
```

The error is:

```
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/antonio/python/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
self.run()
  File "/home/antonio/python/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: words_worker() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the arguments you pass to the process:

```
args=(words_manager['my_dict'])
```

The braces are not interpreted as tuple, so you're not passing a sequence of arguments to the `args`. Instead you should explicitly create a 1-element tuple by placing `,` at the end:

```
args=(words_manager['my_dict'],)
```

From the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

If I use a comma after the element, it runs properly

`args=(words_manager['my_dict'],)`

I suppouse that without the comma, Python interprets each value from the dictionary as an argument, but with the comma it is treated as a tuple with words_manager['my_dict'] as a sole argument.